# Command that runs when the user joins in a specific voice channel discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to make "join to create" system on my discord bot but first I should detect the member joins in a voice channel.How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_voice#discord.on_voice_state_update) event

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if not before.channel and after.channel:
        print(member, 'joined', after.channel)
```